# How to get geth syncing

Tags: go-ethereum, ether

I have get 1.7.2. on Ubuntu 16.04, which is currently stucked at block 3768477
and is not syncing (eth.syncing = false). How do I get it to sync (and not loose my accounts on which I already have some ether).
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the command

geth removedb

then

```
geth --light or geth --fast --cache=1024
```

^ this will remove you current chain so you can start clean, then geth --light is super fast for me its a few minutes and if you choose geth --fast it will be faster than a normal sync but slower than using --light.

Comment: Thanks! So this way I do not loose accounts?

Comment: your account is in your keystore.json file < back this up as a best practice generally.  removedb will remove the chain not your keystore.json file.  Don't panic if you see zero balance just wait for the chain to download.